# Show WPF validation error message in a fixed place

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm

I got WPF validation running (added `ValidationRules` to the binding) and with the template I can create nice adorners. There are many posting out there.

But I cannot find a way to display the error message outside of the adorned control in a fixed place like a `TextBlock` in a corner of the window e.g.

How could I achieve this? Can I bind all of my validation error messages to my `DataContext` (ViewModel here)?

---

Update: Thanks to an answer I got it partly working. The validation messages are now displayed in another label. As all the textboxes with their validation rules are created on the fly by code, the binding to do so is done this way:

```
Binding bindSite = new Binding();
bindSite.Source = this.validationErrorDisplayLabel;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(textBox, Validation.ValidationAdornerSiteProperty, bindSite);
```

But the validation messages are only forwarded to the `adornersite` for the last textbox for which this code was executed.

---

I reproduced the problem in this small example.

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox 
        Validation.ValidationAdornerSite="{Binding ElementName=ErrorDisplay}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding>
                <Binding.Path>Box1</Binding.Path>
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <local:RuleA />
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
    <TextBox 
        Validation.ValidationAdornerSite="{Binding ElementName=ErrorDisplay}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,38,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding>
                <Binding.Path>Box2</Binding.Path>
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <local:RuleA />
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
    <TextBlock 
        x:Name="ErrorDisplay"
        Background="AntiqueWhite"
        Foreground="Red"
        Text="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.ValidationAdornerSiteFor).(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="230,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="2.218,-4.577" Width="177" Height="51"/>
</Grid>
```

The class `RuleA` produces a validation error when the value equals the string `"A"`. The errors in the 2nd textbox are displayed in the TextBlock, the errors of the first one not (instead it uses the default template and gets a red border).

How can it work for both? The textblock does not need to sum up all errors but display the very first error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2008/11/28/using-bindinggroups-for-greater-control-over-input-validation.html I was able to solve this with a BindingGroup and without ValidationAdornerSite.

```
<Window x:Class="BindingAndValidation.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BindingAndValidation"
        Title="Binding and Validation" Height="110" Width="425"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        >
    <Grid x:Name="RootElement">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.BindingGroup>
            <BindingGroup Name="LocalBindingGroup">
                <BindingGroup.ValidationRules>
                    <local:RuleGroup />
                </BindingGroup.ValidationRules>
            </BindingGroup>
        </Grid.BindingGroup>
        <TextBox 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus">
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding>
                    <Binding.Path>Box1</Binding.Path>
                    <Binding.BindingGroupName>LocalBindingGroup</Binding.BindingGroupName>
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <local:RuleA />
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
        <TextBox 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,38,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding>
                    <Binding.Path>Box2</Binding.Path>
                    <Binding.BindingGroupName>LocalBindingGroup</Binding.BindingGroupName>
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <local:RuleA />
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=(Validation.Errors), ElementName=RootElement}" MinWidth="100" MinHeight="16" Margin="230,10,0,0" Background="AntiqueWhite" Foreground="Red">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Foreground="Red" Content="{Binding Path=ErrorContent}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="150,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The validation only occurs when you call `CommitEdit`. If you want to have it immediatly like I wished here you can use `LostFocus`

```
    private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.RootElement.BindingGroup.CommitEdit();
    }
```

Of course for a greater project an attached property might help.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a `BindingGroup` in combination with the `Validation.ValidationAdornerSite` and `Validation.ValidationAdornerSiteFor` properties.

[This blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2008/09/08/wpf-bindinggroup-and-validation-feedback.aspx) shows you an example of how to do this.

---

```
<StackPanel x:Name="FormRoot"
            Validation.ValidationAdornerSite="{Binding ElementName=ErrorDisplay}">
  <FrameworkElement.BindingGroup>
    <BindingGroup Name="FormBindingGroup" />
  </FrameworkElement.BindingGroup>

  <TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
      <Binding BindingGroupName="FormBindingGroup"
               UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus"
               Path="Box1">
        <Binding.ValidationRules>
          <l:RuleA />
        </Binding.ValidationRules>
      </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
  </TextBox>

<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
      <Binding BindingGroupName="FormBindingGroup"
               UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus"
               Path="Box2">
        <Binding.ValidationRules>
          <l:RuleA />
        </Binding.ValidationRules>
      </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
  </TextBox>

  <ItemsControl x:Name="ErrorDisplay"
                Background="AntiqueWhite"
                Foreground="Red"
                ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                      Path=(Validation.ValidationAdornerSiteFor).(Validation.Errors)}"
                DisplayMemberPath="ErrorContent" />
</StackPanel>
```

To commit the values as the user types, change the `UpdateSourceTrigger` values to `PropertyChanged`.  Note that it isn't strictly necessary to use `ValidationAdornerSite` here; you could simply point the `ErrorDisplay` binding directly to the owner of the `BindingGroup`:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=FormRoot, Path=(Validation.Errors)}"
```

Comment: Thanks for your hints! With `Validation.ValidationAdornerSite` and `Validation.ValidationAdornerSiteFor` I got the validation result to another control. But it only worker for errors in the last textbox assigned an `..AdornerSite`.

Comment: I awarded this answer as it helped me although my solution got in another direction. Thanks. See accepted answer for what was my final solution.